# Problem creating MySQL Table at runtime with Delphi XE7 and MyDac

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a favour for a friend, his regular programmer is off sick and he offered me a temporary job.

I'm trying to create a database for him, using RAD Studio XE7 Delphi and MyDac. I'm retired and it's been a while since I used Delphi and that was XE3. I can create the database no problem, but I'm having a problem with the table. It tells me that I have a syntax error in the last line before I execute. I can't put show the actual fields that he wants, but I created a table years ago, also with a very old version of MyDac for my wife. I tried using my old code, and get the same result.

Here is the code :

```
   Form1.MyCommand1 := TMyCommand.Create(nil);
    try
      Form1.MyCommand1.Connection := Form1.MyConnection1;
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE films (');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' series varchar(25) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' id int(11) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' dvd_no int(11) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' title varchar(40) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' actor1 varchar(30) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' actor2 varchar(30) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' director varchar(40) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' writer varchar(40) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' season varchar(30) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' episodes varchar(30) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' year varchar(4) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' genre varchar(30) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' rating varchar(15) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' comment longtext default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' seen char(1) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(' multisession char(1) default NULL, ');
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(');');
      Form1.MyCommand1.Execute;
  finally
    Form1.MyCommand1.Free;
  end;
```

To be honest, I've forgotten what the line "Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(');'); was actually for. I've tried modifying it numerous times, but no luck.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but as I said, it's been a long time and at 80, the gray cells aren't what they used to be!

Can anyone give me a helping hand please?

Comment: Omit the last comma (must become `.Add( ' multisession char(1) default NULL ' );`). Your last `.Add( ');' );` is fine. As usual: the error message tells you where it starts not making sense anymore, so the mistake has to be BEFORE that.

Comment: "To be honest, I've forgotten what the line "`Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add(');');` was actually for". I am pretty sure you can figure it out. Written in abbreviated form, the SQL is `create table films( series, id, dvd_no, ... );` If you omit this line, you get instead `create table films( series, id, dvd_no, ... `. Compare with English: Do you see the difference between `I love dogs (and cats)` and `I love dogs (and cats`?

Comment: Also, regarding the syntax error: Do you see the difference between `I love dogs, cats, rats.` and `I love dogs, cats, rats,.`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. AmigoJack hit the nail on the head. It's so obvious when someone points it out, but the little gray cells miss tiny things like that as you get older. Either don't get older or never stop writing code. I managed to add an autoincrement field and a primary key. It all works fine now. Seems you can't add index fields yet with MyDac. I would have thought they would have fixed that by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
   Form1.MyCommand1 := TMyCommand.Create(nil);
   try
      Form1.MyCommand1.Connection := Form1.MyConnection1;
      Form1.MyCommand1.SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE films (' +
                               ' series varchar(25) default NULL, ' +
                               ' id int(11) default NULL, ' +
                               ' dvd_no int(11) default NULL, ' +
                               ' title varchar(40) default NULL, ' +
                               ' actor1 varchar(30) default NULL, ' +
                               ' actor2 varchar(30) default NULL, ' +
                               ' director varchar(40) default NULL, ' +
                               ' writer varchar(40) default NULL, ' +
                               ' season varchar(30) default NULL, ' +
                               ' episodes varchar(30) default NULL, ' +
                               ' year varchar(4) default NULL, ' +
                               ' genre varchar(30) default NULL, ' +
                               ' rating varchar(15) default NULL, ' +
                               ' comment longtext default NULL, ' +
                               ' seen char(1) default NULL, ' +
                               ' multisession char(1) default NULL);';
      Form1.MyCommand1.Execute;
  finally
      Form1.MyCommand1.Free;
  end;
```

I'm not 100% sure about the last semicolon. If still an error, try this:

```
                               ' multisession char(1) default NULL)';
```

Comment: Yes, the semicolon is perfectly fine (and best practice, I think).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. just removing the comma worked perfectly. It's so obvious. It does prove a point. Either don't get old (bit difficult) or don't take a break from programming.